# Finding difference of item from one list to another list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with some following vector values

```py
list1 = [[-27.1785, -20.7318, -40.724]]
list2 = [[-27.1785, -20.7318, -40.724], [-27.1786, -20.7318, -40.724], [27.1786, -20.7318, -40.724]]
```

As you can see the index 0 and 1 from the `list2` are in `list1`, but I cannot wrap my head around on how to find the vector values that are in the list1 on the list2 and then print out the vector value that is not the same which should be `[27.1786, -20.7318, -40.724]`.

Comment: From your description it seems like you want the sublist that is in both `list1` and `list2`, is that correct?

Comment: The `list1` will always have one sublist item on it, the `list2` is the one that will return many sublists, I would like to use the result I get from `list1` as a "search key" to delete all the sublist items in the `list2` to then get a new list with the list items that are not in `list1`.
I tried to get an numpy array but it might not be the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1 =  [[-27.1785, -20.7318, -40.724]]
l2 = [[-27.1785, -20.7318, -40.724], [-27.1786, -20.7318, -40.724], [-27.1786, -20.7318, -40.724]]

z = [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]
b_set = set(map(tuple,z))
b = list(map(list,b_set))
print(b)
```